# How can I read a group of unrelated objects in a list or other sorting method?

Tags: c#, oop, sorting

I am trying to achieve a detachable/interchangeable Façade Class in my program. The ultimate goal is to have one point of reference, and then the Façade takes control of the rest.

I have looked into Arrays and Lists, but so far I have been unsuccessful in finding a method of reading a group of unrelated objects. I have also looked into Derived and Inherited classes, and also Interfaces, but my understanding of these is not strong enough for me to be confident in implementing them.

As an example, two objects so far might be:

```
User_Model()
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string UserPassword { get; set; }
    string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    int AccessLevel {get; set; }
}

PAC_Model()
{
    int AreaCode {get; set; }
    string AreaName {get; set; }
    string Comments {get; set; }
}
```

Plus many others, some having up to 20 variables.

The method of identifying these objects will be to read the data in the object, then decide what they are/what to do with them.

Can anyone suggest a way of reading these models, or implementing a way to unify them for identification?

**As per request** some Psuedo code for reference of what I would like to achieve:

```
int modelID = 0;

public Sort_models(Type(Model))
{
    if (Type(Model) exists)
    {
        if (Model is User_Model) { modelID = 1; }
        else
            if (Model is PAC_Model) { modelID = 2; }
            else { modelID = 0; }

        Model_Switch();
    }
}

private Model_Switch()
{
    switch(modelID)
    {
        case 1:
            run Login_Compare method();
        case 2:
            run PAC_Compare method();
        default:
            Console.Writeline("No Model Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code or even pseudocode might help us understand your goal

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface `MyInterface` which all of your classes will implement. Then create a list (`List<MyInterface>()`) and work with that. 
Much uglier way would be to define a list of objects and work with elements using "typeof" statemets.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to feed your Façade with an arbitrary object while still hiding all the internal complexity, you will have to use **typeof** or **.GetType()** stuff.
As an example of some abstract Processor Façade:

```
interface IProcessorFacade
{
    void AddHandler<T>(Action<T> handler);
    void Process<T>(T item);
}
```

concrete implementation:

```
class Processor : IProcessorFacade
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> handlers;

    public Processor()
    {
        this.handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

        this.AddHandler<One>(item => Console.WriteLine("Item One has been processed"));
        this.AddHandler<Two>(item => Console.WriteLine("Item Two has been processed"));
        this.AddHandler<Three>(item => Console.WriteLine("Item Three has been processed"));
    }

    public void AddHandler<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        this.handlers[typeof(T)] = item => handler((T)item);
    }

    public void Process<T>(T item)
    {
        Action<object> handler;
        if (this.handlers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handler))
            handler(item);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Handler for type {0} has not been set", typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

Some object classes:

```
class One
{
}

class Two
{   
}

class Three
{   
}

class Four
{
}
```

And let's feed some objects to our processor:

```
IProcessorFacade processor = new Processor();

processor.Process(new One());
processor.Process(new Two());
processor.Process(new Three());

try
{
    processor.Process(new Four());
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Output would be:

```
Item One has been processed
Item Two has been processed
Item Three has been processed
Handler for type Four has not been set
```

Comment: And don't be afraid of `typeof` and `.GetType()` - sometimes they may provide a much cleaner solution than inheritance/interface/overload/override equilibristics. But surely you better learn this equilibristics)